# Why does Vec.sort() seem to require a static lifetime?

Tags: vector, rust, traits, lifetime, trait-objects

This is a vastly simplified example of the issue I'm running into, but given a `trait Thing` which implements `Ord`, and a `struct Object` which implements `Thing`, I have the following struct:

```rust
pub struct MyStruct<'a> {
    my_things: HashMap<i32, Vec<Box<dyn Thing + 'a>>>
}

impl<'a> MyStruct<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> MyStruct<'a> {
        MyStruct {
            my_things: HashMap::new()
        }
    }
    
    pub fn add_object(&mut self, key: i32, obj: Object) {
        if !self.my_things.contains_key(&key) {
            self.my_things.insert(key, Vec::new());
        }
        
        let new_thing: Box<dyn Thing> = Box::new(obj);
        let things = self.my_things.get_mut(&key).unwrap();
        
        things.push(new_thing);
        things.sort();
    }
}
```

It essentially takes a key and an `Object`, and adds the object to a `HashMap` of `Vec`s using the given key. I know this isn't the optimal way to do this but I wanted to keep it simpler for illustration.

The compiler complains on the call to `things.sort()` with the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:58:16
   |
58 |         things.sort();
   |                ^^^^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected trait `Ord`
              found trait `Ord`
note: the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 42:6...
  --> src/main.rs:42:6
   |
42 | impl<'a> MyStruct<'a> {
   |      ^^
   = note: ...does not necessarily outlive the static lifetime
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=86b049e172182468d67b0b1268ada9fe)

If I remove all of the `'a` lifetimes in this example, the code will compile. But for my actual use case, I need to allow non-static lifetimes.

Can someone explain what's going on here? Does `sort()` really require the `Vec` to contain items with static lifetimes? If so why?

Is there a good workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only implemented `Ord` for `dyn Thing + 'static`. The `'static` lifetime bound is inferred if you don't explicitly specify any other lifetime bound. To implement `Ord` for non-`'static` `dyn Thing`s you need to introduce and use a generic lifetime parameter, e.g. `'a`, in your implementations. Updated compiling example:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::cmp;

pub trait Thing {
    fn priority(&self) -> i32;
}

impl<'a> PartialEq for dyn Thing + 'a { // 'a added here
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.priority() == other.priority()
    }
}

impl<'a> PartialOrd for dyn Thing + 'a { // 'a added here
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<cmp::Ordering> {
        self.priority().partial_cmp(&other.priority())
    }
}

impl<'a> Eq for dyn Thing + 'a {} // 'a added here

impl<'a> Ord for dyn Thing + 'a { // 'a added here
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> cmp::Ordering{
        self.priority().cmp(&other.priority())
    }
}

pub struct Object {
    priority: i32,
}

impl Thing for Object {
    fn priority(&self) -> i32 {
        self.priority
    }
}

pub struct MyStruct<'a> {
    my_things: HashMap<i32, Vec<Box<dyn Thing + 'a>>>
}

impl<'a> MyStruct<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> MyStruct<'a> {
        MyStruct {
            my_things: HashMap::new()
        }
    }
    
    pub fn add_object(&mut self, key: i32, obj: Object) {
        if !self.my_things.contains_key(&key) {
            self.my_things.insert(key, Vec::new());
        }
        
        let new_thing: Box<dyn Thing> = Box::new(obj);
        let things = self.my_things.get_mut(&key).unwrap();
        
        things.push(new_thing);
        things.sort();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let _test = MyStruct::new();
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fc866d31591f628cb3a087ac1397d94e)

---

From [the *Default Trait Object Lifetimes* section of the *Lifetime Elision* chapter of the *Rust Reference*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#default-trait-object-lifetimes) (emphasis mine):

> If the trait object is used as a type argument of a generic type then the containing type is first used to try to infer a bound.
>
> - If there is a unique bound from the containing type then that is the default
> - If there is more than one bound from the containing type then an explicit bound must be specified
>
> If neither of those rules apply, then the bounds on the trait are used:
>
> - If the trait is defined with a single lifetime bound then that bound is used.
> - If 'static is used for any lifetime bound then 'static is used.
> - *If the trait has no lifetime bounds, then the lifetime is inferred in expressions and is `'static` outside of expressions.*

Comment: Oh of course! I didn't even think about lifetimes on the trait but that makes complete sense now why the compiler sees a lifetime mismatch. Thank you!